# vscode crashes on Arch linux when opening file/folder

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, crash, archlinux

#### Installation vscode

I'm running Arch Linux (Manjaro) and installed vscode with:

```
sudo pacman -S code
```

but then a simple .NET core program resulted in

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
You may only use the Microsoft .NET Core Debugger (clrdbg) with Visual Studio
Code, Visual Studio or Visual Studio for Mac software to help you develop and
test your applications.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It seems like the official Microsoft build should be obtained via the snap store:

```
sudo snap install code --classic
```

And the program looks normal. I can install plug-ins, create a new file *et cetera*.

#### Problem

However, I cannot open any files or projects. Doing so results in vscode crashing. I read that `code --disable-gpu` could solve this problem, but doesn't do so for me.
Any ideas

- what may cause this crash?
- or how to get the `pacman vscode` working?

#### Logs

```
$ code --verbose
Gtk-Message: 22:59:19.805: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: 22:59:19.805: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
(code:33833): GdkPixbuf-WARNING **: 22:59:19.817: Cannot open pixbuf loader module file '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders.cache': No such file or directory

This likely means that your installation is broken.
Try running the command
  gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders > /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders.cache
to make things work again for the time being.
[33863:1104/225919.911481:ERROR:appcenter_api.cc(52)] expecting appcenter url prefix
[main 2020-11-04T21:59:19.960Z] Sending env to running instance...
[main 2020-11-04T21:59:20.041Z] Sent env to running instance. Terminating...
[main 2020-11-04T21:59:20.041Z] Lifecycle#kill()
```

where the recommended `gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders > /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders.cache`  results in `bash: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders.cache: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1):

> I'm running Arch Linux (Manjaro) and installed vscode with:
>
> ```
> sudo pacman -S code
> ```
>
> but then a simple .NET core program resulted in
>
> ```
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> You may only use the Microsoft .NET Core Debugger (clrdbg) with Visual Studio
> Code, Visual Studio or Visual Studio for Mac software to help you develop and
> test your applications.
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ```

I had the same issue trying to get the debugger to work and I spent hours on finding the reason for this. What I found out is that the debugger only works with officially signed Microsoft binaries of VSCode. So you have to make a distinction here:

- The package `code` contains the open source version of visual studio code, a build wich anyone can make using the provided sources by Microsoft. The program which you get here is therefore *not signed by MS*!
- The package `visual-studio-code-bin` provided by the [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/visual-studio-code-bin/) contains a *officially signed version by MS*. If you use this package, the debugger works as expected.

I do not know wether `snap` - which I personally never used at all - provides this kind of package, so I can not tell anything about that, but using the said package from the user repository solved the problem for me reliably.

Try this one (which I installed just yesterday under the recent manjaro distribution and it worked fine) and see if this solves your problem with opening files and folders.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll try this!